# modify datarow value for a specific gridview column

Tags: asp.net

how would i change the value IBM to something arbitrary like Cisco in one of the gridview events listed?

there can be varying columns in the dynamic gridview so would be nice to address the column by name.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("TestTable");
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("id"), new DataColumn("customername") });
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "1";
            dr[1] = "Microsoft";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
            dr2[0] = "2";
            dr2[1] = "IBM";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }

        protected void GridView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This won't work when [AutogenerateColumns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) is set to `true`(default). You need to add the columns programmatically or declaratively(in aspx markup). Then you can use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) with a Control like `Label` that you can reference in codebehind:

For example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LblCustomer" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

[RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) is perfect(for almost everything):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
        var row = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem).Row;
        var lblCustomer = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("LblCustomer");
        var customerName = row.Field<String>( "customername" );
        if(customerName == "Microsoft") {
            customerName = "Cisco";
        }
        lblCustomer.Text = customerName;
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Ok, never needed to do such. But actually you can change the *Microsoft* values to *Cisco* even with `AutoGenerateColumns` set to `true`.

[DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkx0cy6d.aspx) event is triggered before the `GridView` is databound. If you change the datasource before it's bound to grid, you'll be able to modify it:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tbl = (DataTable)((GridView)sender).DataSource;
    var msRows = tbl.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(r => r.Field<String>("customername") == "Microsoft")
        .Select(r => r);
    foreach(DataRow msRow in msRows) {
        msRow[ "customername" ] = "Cisco";
    }
}
```

<sub>Note: of course you can also use a simple loop instead of LINQ</sub>